# Two finger scrolling on asus Zenbook ux303ln

Tags: touchpad, scrolling

After installing ubuntu on this machine I cannot two-finger/side scroll is there a way of simply mending this?
I have already tried the settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this command

```
dmesg | grep pnp
```

gives output of FLT0101, FLT0102, or FLT0103, you have a Focaltech touchpad.

If you have Ubuntu 15.04, then install touchpad driver

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/focaltech-dkms
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install focaltech-dkms
```

Touchpad will work normally after reboot.

This will also work for Ubuntu 14.04, but will pull 3.19 kernel.

**UPDATE:** These touchpads are now supported by the 4.2 kernels.
The kernel can be installed by

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily
```

The Focaltech driver from the PPA should be removed.